# Is there a third party platform where I can host a large image gallery and then embed into my website with an iframe?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, hosting, pagespeed, image-gallery

I have a WordPress website where I am using the Essential Grid plugin for my gallery on one of the pages. The gallery is almost up to over 2000 images, and I have to regularly upload more onto the site.

The images are optimized and don't exceed much over 250kb in size. However, this page is really slow as a result, and it is slowing down the rest of the site as well.

**Is there a third-party platform that you know of that can host a gallery like this and then be embedded into my site with an iframe?**

Preferably, I would like to be able to have a filter on the gallery that filters the images based on tags/categories that I can assign the images.

I have tried using Essential grid to host the gallery of over 2000 images, but it cannot sustain the massive amount of images without becoming really slow.

Comment: 2000 images with 250kb size makes 0.5 GB of data - in whichever location you host the pictures, it will take a long time for all of them to load. Thats why most galleries create small preview thumbnails, use pagination, ajax loading...

Comment: I think you are mis-using this plugin. 2.000 images in 1 gallery, do you want to host an image database? Then, you don't need a gallery but an image search with pagination, thumbnails etc. as already mentioned.